# place current_user data into different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

Hello I am trying to make a form submit data from the user that is filling out the form. I want a hidden_form that can pull the current_user.name and current_user.email from the person that is submitting the form. I am using Devise and mongoid(mongoid doesn't make a difference but I wanted to give more detail). Here is what I have so far...

form view...

```
<%= form_for [:managers, Reportapproval.new] do |f| %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.hidden_field :current_manager.name => :reportapproval.manager_name %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :current_manager.email => :reportapproval.manager_email %>
      </div>
```

When I try to render this view I get the error

"undefined method `name' for :current_manager:Symbol".

I need the name and email of the current user to go to the reportapproval model and submit along with the info that the manager fills out in the form.

Here is the reportapproval model...

```
class Reportapproval
  include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :applicant
    belongs_to :manager
    has_many :reports

  field :manager_approved,            type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false
  field :tenant_approved,             type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false
  field :manager_name
  field :manager_email
```

Comment: try this `<%=f.hidden_field :manager_name, :value => reportapproval.manager_name%>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written current_manager a symbol. that's why you are getting error `"undefined method`name' for :current_manager:Symbol".`

You have to write like this for form_for:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :manager_name, :value => current_manager.name %>
```